# From Dreamweaver to Visual studio (code) with Azure

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, dreamweaver

I try to make the move from Dreamweaver to Visual Studio Code. We're developing an web application in Azure. So in Dreamweaver I add the site in dreamweaver settings and we can start coding. Now I want to do the same in VSC but I cannot find it in the menu and also could not find an answer to this (obvious) question on the internet (so far).

So, where do I define user settings, a link to my azure development site, etc?

Or is there another best practice to code Azure web applications with VSC. We work in an team of developers.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Vscode has multiple extensions that can help you develop in a good env despite your programming language or platform. Just install extensions by clicking `ctrl+shift+x` and search your own, to open user settings and tweak them click `ctrl+shift+p` and type `settings`, this will show you a list with all settings that your editor or extensions have.

Comment: I'm more or less looking for some best practice. I guess there will be people out there who have don the same before. Would really appreciate that.